# Laravel Queueable Notification after deleting Model not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, notifications, laravel-5.3

I'm using L5.3.

I have a lot of Queueable Laravel Notifications, they are working fine with Redis. Except notifications related to deleting of some Eloquent Model.

Here is Notification source example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications\Games;

use App\Helpers\NotificationHelper;
use App\Game;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class Deleted extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
  use Queueable;

  public $game;
  private $game_id;

  public function __construct($game_id)
  {
    $this->game_id = $game_id;
    $this->game = Game::withTrashed()->with('situation')->find($game_id);
    // Log::info($this->game) here shows everything is ok
  }

  /**
   * Get the notification's delivery channels.
   *
   * @param  mixed $notifiable
   * @return array
   */
  public function via($notifiable)
  {
    return ['database'];
  }

  /**
   * Get the array representation of the notification.
   *
   * @param  mixed $notifiable
   * @return array
   */
  public function toDatabase($notifiable)
  {
    return [
      'game_id' => $this->game->id,
      'html' => '' . view('notifications.games.deleted', ['id' => $this->id, 'game' => $this->game, 'notifiable' => $notifiable])
    ];
  }
}
```

And there is how I send it:
`$user->notify(new Deleted($id));`

If I remove `implements ShouldQueue`, notification works. But I need queues because of using several external services (like Telegram, Facebook, One signal etc) and some notifications could be sent to lot of users.

There are also no errors in `storage\logs\laravel.log` and `storage\logs\worker.log` files. No items in `failed_jobs` table.

And yes, I am using `soft deleting` of models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I found 2 solutions, posting both:

It's not a real solution, seems more like a dirty hack to me, because depending on situation it could make you wrote much more code.

```
// Change Eloquent to Array in constructor
$this->game = Game::withTrashed()->with('situation')->find($game_id)->toArray();

// And then change all your toDatabase, toMail, toFacebook etc methods: use $game['name'] instead of $game->name etc.
```

This is what I decided to use:

```
// Remove $game from constructor...
public function __construct($game_id)
  {
    $this->game_id = $game_id;
  }

// Then add it to your toDatabase, toMail, toFacebook etc methods:
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
  {
    $game = Game::withTrashed()->with('situation')->find($this->game_id);
    return [
      'game_id' => $this->game_id,
      'html' => '' . view('notifications.games.deleted', ['id' => $this->id, 'game' => $game, 'notifiable' => $notifiable])
    ];
  }
```

Using second method, we will retrieve Game model from DB 2 times if we have 2 notification channels, 10 times if we have 10 channels.. Yes, this is overhead, but we able to use all Eloquent Collection helpers etc. This is why I chosen second method instead of arrays. I hope this helps someone someday.

And I'll be glad to hear why we can't get Eloquent model in constructor.